# I want to post images on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I created a form that can post images like this, and tried to process the images as I examined
**view**

```
<form  action="{{ $action }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="imagefile" accept="image/*">
 <input type="text" name="content">
 <button tyoe="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Processing with the controller took out the image and saved the place while watching other people's blog

```
$post_data = $request->except('imagefile');
$imagefile = $request->file('imagefile');
$temp_path = $imagefile->store('public/temp');

$a = new Test;
$a->fill($request->all())->save();
```

I thought it was going well, but there was an error

> Cannot insert value NULL into 'imagefile'

I checked after that but the cause is not understood.

Comment: "Form" must have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, like this : `<form method="post" action="example.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @NgocNam I'm sorry, the actual form has it but I forgot to write it

Comment: Maybe the problem is `$a->fill($request->all())->save();`, because imagefile was set to object "a" ,imagefile field/column be null, you try to debug, set `$a->imagefile` be an empty string before `save` (insert) it.

Comment: @NgocNam It might work if you assign it before saving

Comment: So, the problem is inserting. Because imagefile is an object, you must find path of image then set it into imagefile field of object $a, then insert into DB, otherwise, you must change imagefile type to store an object.

Comment: @NgocNam May I tell you what happens if I write it only in PHP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203291/discussion-between-ngoc-nam-and-su3158).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it May help You..

```
$post_data = $request->except('imagefile');
$imagefile = $request->file('imagefile');
$temp_path = $imagefile->store('public/temp');
$filename = $request->file('image');
$post_data->imagefile = $filename;

$a = new Test;
$a->fill($post_data)->save();
```

**or**

```
$a = new Test;
$a->imagefile = $filename; // here imagefile equal to your db fild
$a->save();
```

Comment: please explain it.

Comment: I don't know the cause yet, but it seems to be long

Comment: This error Save () gives The identity column 'id' cannot be updated.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The image problem is solved
An error with data save () is another matter

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign file name to the values array before save. Also don't use `$request->all();` this contains image object too & we don't need it when saving. We only need the file name. In below code i have assign the file name into $post_data array before save it.

```
$post_data = $request->except('imagefile');
$imagefile = $request->file('imagefile');
$temp_path = $imagefile->store('public/temp');

$filename = $request->file('image')->hashName();
$post_data->imagefile = $filename;

$a = new Test;
$a->fill($post_data)->save();
```

Comment: Does everything in the request fall on post_date?

Comment: post_data contains everything except imagefile object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below line to get all parameters regarding your image.

$imagefile = $_FILES;

print the $imagafile array before proceeding.